# value of getenv() not working in strtok()

Tags: c, char, strtok

```
char *p = strtok (argv[1], ",")    #  Works perfectly
char *p = strtok (getenv("somestring"), ","); # does not work
```

In my program I take value of **argv[1]** which is passed like **"x,y"** format
. when argv[1] is not given , then my program should take value from
**getenv("somestring")**  which  also returns  **"x,y"**
after that i parse them using strtok.

I do not why argv[1] and getenv() behaving the same way since they both are of same data typr if i m not mistaken

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I don't think it is guaranteed to be legal, because `strtok` alters the string it was passed, and these are not "your" strings.

Comment: According to at least [one reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/getenv), it's undefined behavior: "Modifying the string returned by getenv invokes undefined behavior."

Comment: If you apply `strtok()` to the result of `getenv()`, you're probably changing the value of the environment variable too — whether you intended to or not.  Assume the return value from `getenv()` is not modifiable.  Either use something other than `strtok()` — `strcspn()` for example — or make a copy of the string it returns (`strdup()`?) and hack that copy instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From notes in [`getenv`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv) manual:

> As typically implemented, getenv() returns a pointer to a string within the environment list.  The caller must take  care  not
>   to modify this string, since that would change the environment of the process.

As `strtok` modifies the string, you have to copy the string returned by `getenv` and then call `strtok` using the copy:

```
char *str, *ptr;
char *p = getenv("somestring");
str = malloc(strlen(p) + 1);
strcpy(str, p);
ptr = strtok(str, ",");

// Make sure to deallocate the memory once you are done using it.
free(str);
```

You can use `strdup` too:

```
char *str, *ptr;
char *p = getenv("somestring");
str = strdup(p);
ptr = strtok(str, ",");

// Make sure to deallocate the memory once you are done using it.
free(str);
```

Comment: `strncpy(str, p, strlen(p))` is redundant. The point of `strncpy` is to provide the _destination_ size, not the source size. If the destination and the source sizes are the same, then you can (and should) call `strcpy`.